# Vertically align 2 floating divs with flexible height

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to figure out how to align 2 floating divs vertically. Each of the divs has a flexible height.

Here is what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/VLRpc/1/

```
 <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="column left">
                <h1>Software</h1>
                <p>I use many software applications to achieve the best results.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column right"></div>
        </div><!-- end wrap -->
</div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end section -->

.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: table;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Columns */
.column {
width: 45%;
height: auto;
float:left;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.right {
margin-left:0;
height: 250px
}
.left {
margin-left:5%;
}
```

However the div on the left gets pushed to the top of the larger div which is on the right. I need both of these divs to be vertically centered.

Any ideas?

Comment: absolute or float kills any display values, or you use display(table/table-cell - inline-block ) to vertical-align , or use absolute or float with funny negative margin :), i guess you get what my choice would be :)

Comment: Can you supply an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VLRpc/3/ something like this ?

Comment: or like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/VLRpc/4/

Comment: Yes using display:inline and vertical align middle on the column class does the trick

Comment: Bradley I wonder if you have your question correctly written. Are you asking how you can get both divs to have an equal height when one div has height specified and the other does not?

Comment: No, Both divs will have unknown height but need to be vertically centered. See the answer below

Comment: oh I did not see the part you wrote at the bottom, about the center

Comment: @michael Falciglia, the question did not really matter when you see where the mistake was the use of display method killed by  float/absolute where vertical-align cannot be applied anymore :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you could make it flexible (no fixed heights, just keep those .column containers vertically centered regardless of their content): set .column to display:inline-block and to vertical-align: middle inside your table-cell .wrap div.

```
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VLRpc/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, just change the margin-top value in the left column, and all should be good. If you want more content in that column, add some padding-top too. Here is the changed css for it:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Columns */
.column {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:0;
}
.right {
    margin-left:0;
    height: 250px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 1.4em;
}
```

Comment: I hope that's what you meant, if not let me know! :)

Comment: The only problem with this is that one of the columns has to have a fixed height. And you still don't know the height of the other column so you can't get true centering.

Comment: I don't think you understand his question, he wants to vertically align them. This will only push left top down 50px

Comment: alright, sorry about that. put he can still adjust the padding to fix it slightly. Sry, I tried. :)

Comment: I'm not knocking you, I was just saying you don't understand the question

Comment: no I know you werent, its all good! :) let me know if I can anything else!